# Hiding pagination if #hits has a 1 page result - Algolia InstantSearch.js

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js

I'm new to this and I've been looking for ways to hide the pagination if only 1 or no results are found in the **#hits** container and my pagination just looks like this

```
instantsearch.widgets.pagination({container: '#pagination', padding:'2'})
```